# Python How to have OS block the process and resume on timer

Tags: python-3.x

I have been looking around and I can't seem to find a module that allows me to block the current process until the timer is done. What I don't want to do is utilize the CPU while waiting (busy waiting). I want the process to be blocked/suspended by the operating system and will be automatically notified when the timer is done.

```py
    # use a system call to create a waitable timer
    timer = CreateWaitableTime()

    # use another system call that waits on a waitable object
    WaitFor(timer)  # this will block the current process until the timer is signaled

    # .. sometime in the future, the timer might expire and it's object will be signaled
    #    causing the WaitFor(timer) call to resume operation
    do_other_stuff() # after timer
```

Edit
The reason for this is that I am going to have another process spawn this processes, therefore it doesn't matter if these get blocked. They need to be able to wait without wasting CPU time.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Python by default executes code in a top down manner. So in your example, a simple timer will block the program from executing the function 'do_other_stuff()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from threading import Event

evnt = Event()

wait_for = 5 #seconds
evnt.wait(wait_for) # will block for 5 seconds, or unless set early
```

another thread can call `set` to early finish the wait above

```py
evnt.set()
```